# Is "Sheath" the right word for describing exterior covering of the plane?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can I use this word? Or is there a more suitable one?

Comment: it's just "skin".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, the actual layer of material on the very outside of the entire plane is referred to as its "skin", as distinct from its "skeleton" or "structure" and in much the same sense of the words as a human's skin and skeleton. A similar word is "shell", not often used with planes (as the outer surface is very intricately connected with the structure beneath), but more often with cars and land vehicles, especially racing cars. In ships, the term is usually "hull", and this term can sometimes be used to refer to an aircraft's or (more often) spacecraft's outer layer.

The fuselage of a plane is its main body, as distinct from its wings and tail. It has both a skeleton and a skin (both mainly of aluminum, sometimes carbon fiber), as do the wings and tail. However, neither fuselage, wings or tail could be considered a plane's "outer covering".

Comment: +1, although you'll see the term "sheathing" or "sheathed" used in old documents (pre-WWII) especially in regards to doped-fabric-over-plywood construction. "Skin" seems to have been preferred for as long as the covering has been a stressed part of the airframe.

Answer (score 2):

Exterior covering material in general can be called *[sheathing](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=sheathing)*, but I don't know if I've every seen that used for an airplane. (Ships and houses, yes, but not planes.)

Answer (score 1):

If the fuselage's skin is used as the actual load-bearing, structural surface (rather than sheathing on an internal frame), it's called a [**monocoque**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocoque) construction.  The exoskeleton of a beetle could be called monococque (although I don't think anybody ever actually does.)

Comment: I don't believe the outer surface of any plane I've ever met has been structural. Trying to construct a plane that way would probably result in something that's so heavy it has no hope of ever leaving the ground, nevermind flying.

Comment: The Albatros DIII (Richthofen's plane) and the deHavilland Mosquito were a couple of examples of monococques; there have been others, but you're right: in a plane over a certain size, a monococque is too heavy.  However, there's this: "To overcome the strength-to-weight problem of monocoque design, a modification called *semimonocoque* design was developed and is widely used on aircraft such as all Boeing Commercial Aircraft like the 737..."  You've probably flown in one of *those*...

Comment: @Martha, it's completely normal for the skin to be a structural element.  (Not the **only** structural element, but 100% structural.)

Answer (score 0):

The word you're probably looking for is **[fuselage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuselage)**. From Wikipedia:

> The fuselage (pronounced
>   /ˈfjuːzəlɑːʒ/; from the French fuselé
>   "spindle-shaped") is an aircraft's
>   main body section that holds crew and
>   passengers or cargo.

Comment: Agreed.  A sheath is commonly a covering, as in a storage and/or protective case, particularly for a knife or sword.  The contained object is intended to be removed from its covering.  I certainly hope your aircraft does not intend to shed its outer covering!

Comment: It's really NOT the fuselage, Ben, sorry.  The fuselage is simply the "body" of the plane -- ie, not the wings or tail.  It's that simple. ("Cabin" or "body" means almost the same as "fuselage".)  The word "fuselage" has no relation to the skin - note that the fuselage **has** skin, as does the tail, wings, nose, etc.

Comment: @Joe Blow. No, the fuselage is not the same thing as the skin. However, it _might_ be the word he's looking for.